# Add a parameter to a SQL where clause column_name for a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters

I am trying to add a couple parameters to a where clause in place of the `column_name` and value. Everything I have seen online has given an example of a parameter for the value of the column already in the stored procedure, but not for the column itself.

Here is what I have so far:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [mobile].[p_get_insptn_log_by_date]
    (@SEARCHBY SYSNAME, @SEARCHVALUE NVARCHAR(100))
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT 
        [id], [application_name], [login_id], [log_ts],
        [insptn_log_msg_type_code], [log_msg_text], [insptn_log_lvl_code]
    FROM 
        [dbo].[Insptn_log]
    WHERE 
        insptn_log_lvl_code <> 'info' AND
        CASE 
           WHEN @SEARCHBY = 'application_name' 
              THEN application_name = @SEARCHVALUE
           WHEN @SEARCHBY = 'login_id' 
              THEN login_id = @SEARCHVALUE
           WHEN @SEARCHBY = 'log_ts' log_ts < CONVERT(DATETIME, @SEARCHVALUE)
        END
```

As it is, SQL Server Management Studio throws an error saying there a syntax error under the first `=` sign in the case statement and the second `WHEN` in the `CASE` statement.

I am just looking for the correct syntax to accomplish this task. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

+++++EDIT+++++

I did not previously mention that the type of the `@SEARCHVALUE` would have to be able to go from `NVARCHAR` to `DATETIME` when the user selects 'log_ts' as a `@SEARCHBY` value. I also updated the above script for DataTypes of the Params coming in from my MVC application.

Comment: Your @SEARCHBY cannot be a CHAR (it is longer than 1 character).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A much more efficient and sleek way of doing this would be something like......

```
CREATE PROC [mobile].[p_get_insptn_log_by_date]
    @SEARCHBY SYSNAME           = NULL   --<-- Use appropriate data type
  , @SEARCHVALUE NVARCHAR(1000) = NULL   --<-- Use appropriate data length
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
Declare @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Sql = N'SELECT  [id]
                    ,[application_name]
                    ,[login_id]
                    ,[log_ts]
                    ,[insptn_log_msg_type_code]
                    ,[log_msg_text]
                    ,[insptn_log_lvl_code]
            FROM [dbo].[Insptn_log]
            WHERE insptn_log_lvl_code <> ''info''' 
            + CASE WHEN @SEARCHBY IS NOT NULL AND @SEARCHVALUE IS NOT NULL 
              THEN N' AND ' + QUOTENAME(@SEARCHBY) + N' = @SEARCHVALUE' ELSE N'' END

Exec sp_executesql @Sql
                    ,N'@SEARCHVALUE NVARCHAR(1000)'
                    ,@SEARCHVALUE 
END
```

using `sp_executesql` will allow the procedure to cache parameterised execution plans for the same stored procedure. Otherwise with these `case statement` in your where clause you can end up with one execution plan which may be best for a specific set of parameters but not so good for any other set of parameters.

Also always specifically define the length for any varchar/char/nchar/nvarchar variables, else it is set to the sql server default which is `1`. In the cast/convert function the default value is `30` but its best to specifically use the correct length yourself.

Comment: So the SEARCHBY parameter will be the name of the column that the user selects in the application that i am creating, as a string. would i still want to use the SYSNAME type for the parameter?

Comment: @tCoe `SYSNAME` is a data type specifically created to store SQL Server object names (tables , columns , views etc). Yes this would be the best data type for  `@SEARCHBY` variable in your case.

Comment: This worked perfectly once i cleaned up the application side. Thank you.

Comment: @tCoe: `SYSNAME` is a synonym for `NVARCHAR(128)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CREATE PROC [mobile].[p_get_insptn_log_by_date](@SEARCHBY VARCHAR(100), @SEARCHVALUE NVARCHAR )

AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT [id]
,[application_name]
,[login_id]
,[log_ts]
,[insptn_log_msg_type_code]
,[log_msg_text]
, [insptn_log_lvl_code]
FROM [dbo].[Insptn_log]
WHERE insptn_log_lvl_code <> 'info' and
(( @SEARCHBY = 'application_name' AND  application_name = @SEARCHVALUE)
OR ( @SEARCHBY = 'login_id' AND login_id = @SEARCHVALUE)
OR ( @SEARCHBY = 'log_ts' AND log_ts < @SEARCHVALUE)
)
```

Better yet, I think this should be a better way to handle the situation:

```
CREATE PROC [mobile].[p_get_insptn_log_by_date](@SEARCHBY VARCHAR(100), @SEARCHVALUE NVARCHAR )

AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON

IF (@SEARCHBY = 'application_name')
    BEGIN
    SELECT [id]
    ,[application_name]
    ,[login_id]
    ,[log_ts]
    ,[insptn_log_msg_type_code]
    ,[log_msg_text]
    , [insptn_log_lvl_code]
    FROM [dbo].[Insptn_log]
    WHERE insptn_log_lvl_code <> 'info' and application_name = @SEARCHVALUE
    END
ELSE IF (@SEARCHBY = 'login_id')
    BEGIN
    SELECT [id]
    ,[application_name]
    ,[login_id]
    ,[log_ts]
    ,[insptn_log_msg_type_code]
    ,[log_msg_text]
    , [insptn_log_lvl_code]
    FROM [dbo].[Insptn_log]
    WHERE insptn_log_lvl_code <> 'info' and login_id = @SEARCHVALUE
    END
ELSE IF (@SEARCHBY = 'log_ts')
    BEGIN
    SELECT [id]
    ,[application_name]
    ,[login_id]
    ,[log_ts]
    ,[insptn_log_msg_type_code]
    ,[log_msg_text]
    , [insptn_log_lvl_code]
    FROM [dbo].[Insptn_log]
    WHERE insptn_log_lvl_code <> 'info' and log_ts < @SEARCHVALUE
    END;
```

Comment: Both of your suggested solutions will have some serious performance issues :S

Comment: @M.Ali Care to elaborate more?

Comment: Create a table, add about a million rows and create a similar stored procedure for it, pass different values and see how procedure runs then use sp_recompile command to recompile the execution plan before each execution and see how the same procedure behaves with the same values you passed earlier on but without recompiling it.

Comment: The reason why your first suggestion is a performance killer - SQL Server does not do short-circuiting like we have in C# `||` which means if either of the argument in an `OR` statement evaluates to true the who expression is evaluated to true.  Because SQL Server doesnt do short-circuiting even if `@SEARCHBY = 'application_name'` is not evaluated to true SQL Server may still decide to go ahead and evaluate `application_name = @SEARCHVALUE`.

Comment: The reason why your second suggestion is a performance killer - Lets say the user inputs `@SEARCHBY = 'application_name'` for the first execution, at this point sql server would have cached an execution plan which maybe doing a seek on some index on an index on  `application_name` column etc etc. Now when the user passes a different values to  `@SEARCHBY` variable , sql server will still use the same cached plan that it used for the first exection, which may or may not be the best plan for the  `login_id` column.

Comment: I hopeI have elaborated enough, anyway I hope this has given you a different perspective, I did not mean to just criticise you just for the sake of criticism :)

Comment: @M.Ali Thanks for the comments. I appreciate it. :)